# Applications of analytical mechanics in real life

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, applied-physics

I'm currently taking a course of analytical mechanics, I'd like to read more about it. I'm interested in reading about what kind of appliances are there for analytical mechanics in computer science or electrical engineering? I would be really happy to read some articles or research about it. I tried searching online but couldn't find much information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For just one example in each:

- Coupled oscillators are usually quite important in electrical engineering, and the related concept of normal modes is one that is best dealt with using analytical mechanics.
- Methods of numerically solving ODEs like the Runge-Kutta method tend not to conserve energy over long periods of time (i.e. over many timesteps). A class of ODE solvers based on the Hamiltonian formalism allows for energy conservation for those differential equations that are amenable to being cast in such a formalism. More generally, the kind of geometry induced by the behavior of a Hamiltonian dynamical system (symplectic geometry) inspires the many kinds of *symplectic integrators* used for a similar purpose.